# Mac OSX mangles route table randomly after sleeping

Tags: networking, vpn, mac-osx

First post here on ServerFault. Hoping for some insights to a strange issue. This requires some back story, but the TLDR-ish version of the problem is this:  Randomly, my 2021 Macbook Pro will awake from sleep (lid closed) and be unable to connect to ANY network on any interface, wired or wireless.  When this condition is true, the route table (as produced with command 'netstat -rn') has very few routes listed (4 or 5) and NO default route or any reference to the local subnet. Here is a screenshot show a working version of the route table compared to what I'm seeing when the problem is present:  https://www.screencast.com/t/2gSTyhkgf

Here's the back story that I think is relevant to resolving this issue:

1 month ago, I used Apple's migration tool to move my old macbook settings and files to my new (current) one. Included in that migration were network settings (I have a LOT of wifi networks I didn't want to lose). For most of this first month with the new mac, no problems...has worked great. The new mac is an M1 based chip, btw.

I noticed in System Pref > Networks, there were 2 VPNs present that I had not yet installed in the new Macbook, NordVPN and a Sonicwall SSL client. I have/had not tried to use those but they were present as interfaces in Networks, below wifi and my 2 wired NICs (dongles).

Not present in networking, was a third VPN client which is based on Wireguard's tunneling platform. The vendor's name for this is ControlOne. Like the others, I had **NOT** installed this ControlOne application on the new Mac.  However, I noticed after a couple of days that the tunnel was up and my egress was in Texas (I'm in TN).  There was no UI for the ControlOne application so I formally installed it and then disconnected it.  Macbook continued to work normally...the issue presently to be resolved had not appeared yet.

I installed Parallels and built and killed a couple of different Win 11 VMs with it playing with it. I kept the 3rd incarnation of it and used it at several client sites for networking issue resolutions (I'm much more acquainted with Windows networking that Mac and prefer it for solving client issues).  My preferred networking mode with Parallels is to use what they refer to as "bridged" between the Windows VM and the Mac's active interface, typically wireless.  The benefit with their "bridged" mode is both the Mac and the Windows VM get IPs on the current subnet so there's no NAT issues that can interfere with using the Windows VM for network troubleshooting/configs of client stuff, etc. You get the point. Again, this worked normally for a couple weeks.

Enter the beginnings of the problem.  At a diner for lunch waiting on a client office to open for me to do some network work for them, I tried to connect to the diner's wifi, expecting to use my ControlOne VPN once I have a route to the internet. It showed connected, but no IP.  I assumed they had a problem.  Next tried to connect to my iPhone's hotspot, something I do at least once a day if on the road. Same problem...connected, but no IP.  Ignored the coincidence of this and ate my cheeseburger as I didn't have to have it right then.

Got to the client site, a network I built and have interacted with on THIS Macbook several times, but could not connect...same issue, no IP.  Started troubleshooting and found that even if I put in a static IP in the right subnet on any NIC/interface on the macbook, I could not get out.  I most cases I could ping things on the local subnet, but not the internet.  Here's a good one: while this condition was true, my Windows VM in Parallels was working PERFECTLY.  No network issues whatsoever.  DHCP release/renew worked flawlessly.  This was pretty perplexing to me.

I found that if I rebooted my mac, networking would resume, but then falter at some random time (very short time) later, without putting the mac to sleep (closing lid for several minutes).  The clue that got me to the route table was trying to ping something off the local subnet resulted in a "no route to host" notification.

Then I started looking at the route table to see what was going on there and observed what (or something similar if not exact) to what is shown in the screenshots linked above.

As a troubleshooting step, I removed ControlOne VPN by dragging it to the trash.  I don't know of any other method for more thoroughly cleaning up apps on a Mac. This had no effect on the problem.

I next removed Parallels to eliminate it from the equation. No change.

I removed the 2 VPN clients that were present in the network config UI (the NordVPN and Sonicwall SSL client). No change.

My only resolution, and temporary one at that, is to reboot the Mac when this condition presents itself.  I've not yet been able to purposely cause the problem to happen in any predictable way.  That is, I can close the lid on the macbook for 5 min, 30 min, or 2 hours and when I open it, the network problem may or may not appear.  I don't know what the actual trigger for the problem is.

That was a LOT of information. If you're still reading this, then I'm grateful.  If you have any suggestion about what I might do to identify the root issue here, and maybe ideas on how to possibly resolve it without a complete wipe/reload of the macbook, I'm all ears.  I'm happy to compensate someone in some way if we can get to a working resolution!  (not sure if that's done here or not, but there it is).

For what its worth, I've got 20+ years experience as an IT pro, but nearly all of it in Windows.  I started and continue to run an MSP supporting small business clients as a full-stack shop...but this Mac thing is stumping me and Apple support, as nice and prompt as they are, haven't yet understood what a route table even is.  Hitting a dead end there.

Again, thanks for reading. If you have advice, I'd welcome it.

Comment: Serverfault is for questions about server administration, not general computer usage or client troubleshooting; [Superuser](https://superuser.com) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) are better places to ask about things like this. But it sounds like you're just not getting DHCP setup. You shouldn't have to set a static IP on most networks, but if you do you'll also have to configure a default router and DNS server. Check the Network preference pane's status light on the interface and description to the right under Status. Also `ipconfig getpacket en0` to see raw DHCP info.

Comment: Hi. Apologies for the context of Serverfault...I was not aware of the intent. Thanks for contributing your thoughts, nevertheless.  I too have come to the realization that the issue is one of failing to get (apply) DHCP appropriately.  I'm retooling my searching for a possible cause and solution based on this realization.